# Android TCP Client & UI Thread

Tags: android, user-interface, tcp

I know you're not supposed to include slow-acting code on your UI thread in Android applications, but I'm not really sure what constitutes slow and what constitutes fast.

My application includes a permanent TCP Client connection to an external server.  Up to now, I haven't made any serious efforts at configuring its related code to run on secondary threads, and it seems to be working well enough.

Does anybody have strong feelings one way or the other about how an Android application should interact simultaneously with a user and an external TCP Server??

Thanks,
R.

Comment: You're asking for trouble by not running the network related code in a separate thread. It all comes down to this: Are **you** okay with your app _freezing_ (from the users' perspective), and occassional _force closes_ because the network was saturated or communication took too long? If you couldn't be bothered going through the effort now, consider that this will show later on in support requests/low ratings, etc. Again all design decisions **you** will have to live with.

Comment: It's a very good point.  I just haven't seen that behavior.  Oh, I'm seeing of problem, mind you, just not freezes or forced closes...  Also, when I converted my TCP client code to run in a separate thread (1st draft, I admit), it helpfully stopped working at all..  Can you point me to an example TCP client for Android??

Comment: Look into moving your networking code into an `AsyncTask`. It's quite easy to implement and there are tons of examples on SO. I've also answered quite a few AsyncTask questions myself so you're welcome to go through them as well. Here's a [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) article from Android for you to get going. Try it out and if you run into problems, start a new question and @ping me if you haven't got a timely response. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android(or other platforms) the main thread is the UI Thread. This is because the user would always expect good responsiveness while using an application. If you overload this thread with any time consuming tasks, it will appear to the user that the app has frozen. This is against all Design guidelines, and you should definitely start separating your network connections from the main thread.

Comment: Wow. Three essentially identical answers...

I'm sold, I just haven't found a way to make it work.  Has anybody got a lead on some example TCP Client code for Android??

Answer (score 0):

Anything on the network should absolutely be in a background thread.

Infact the android dev team feels so strongly that this is the case, starting in Honeycomb if you try to access network on the main thread an exception is thrown.

The speed and reliability of the network connection is out of your control, by making UI thread deal with the network you are also taking the speed / reliability / responsiveness of your application out of your control. And while it won't always lead to a poor user experience, it will sometimes. And those sometimes are enough IMO to not let it happen.

Comment: Wow. Three essentially identical answers...

I'm sold, I just haven't found a way to make it work.  Has anybody got a lead on some example TCP Client code for Android??

Comment: The answer on this question has a nice example, that is already put into an AsyncTask for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855775/android-tcp-client Also this page contains another nice example http://kikudjiro.posterous.com/android-tcp-client-example that you can download

Answer (score 0):

It simply wont work. As of Android 3.0 network operations on the main thread are an enforced Strict Mode violation and it will just throw and exception.. better learn about asynctasks and loaders now.

Comment: Wow. Three essentially identical answers...

I'm sold, I just haven't found a way to make it work.  Has anybody got a lead on some example TCP Client code for Android??

Comment: These are everywhere .. but try http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html for a start and read up about AsyncTask and Loader like I already mentioned.