# Android TCP fast start configuration

Tags: android, tcp, download

I'm currently working on a project to create an Internet Download Manager for Android. I'm planning to speed up the downloading by changing the normal tcp slow start to tcp fast start. Although I did a research, I couldn't find a solution for how to change the tcp in Android. I'm still a noob to Android Programming. Please help me find how to achieve it, Thank you in advance!

Comment: Go to this [link][1] , see if it helps


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855775/android-tcp-client

Comment: @TRonZ : This is about configuring the Server and the Port. But What I need is to configure the tcp slow start into tcp fast start. I still couldn't find the answer but thanks for your support! :)

Answer (score 1):

TCP Fast Start isn't supported in Android, as of version 4.4. Therefore, this is impossible :(